# Calculate first day of a calendar week

Tags: c, computer-science

I am doing a class project with C and I need to calculate the month and day given a year that is in the 21st century "skipping 2000". 
The teacher has it broken down in steps:

Step one is obtain the last two digits of the year; which I have done with

```
yy = yyyy % 100;
```

Step two is compute 25% of the two digits and drop the decimal by
getting 2- 10%'s of the digits and then adding it to itself; which I have done with

```
result = result + (result/5.0):
```

I am just kind of stuck on how I would drop the decimal place?

Step three is to add our 25% value back to our original two digit number we got in step one.
This is also another step I am stuck on.

Step four is subtract the largest fitting multiple of 7; I have created an array on the top.

Then I need to subtract 1 from our 25% value given that a year that is entered is a leap year.

I have included all I have got for my code right now. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: 
I have fixed my for loop and spent some time on going over my code and I am just stuck on when I try to output the day with "d[ypercent] I get a bunch of jumbled up characters. I have directed ypercent to a string value and I can't seem figure out why. I have posted my updated code as well. I have went over it and it compiles fine but it will not output the correct day.

So my question is: How do I fix the "printf(" January 1st is on a %s :\n", yyyy, d[ypercent]);" to show the correct day?

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {       
    int x = 0;
    int yy, yyyy;
    int lastX, ypercent;
    float result;

    const char *d[7];                                                                                                         
    d[0] = "Sunday";
    d[1] = "Monday";
    d[2] = "Tuesday";
    d[3] = "Wednesday";
    d[4] = "Thursday";
    d[5] = "Friday";
    d[6] = "Saturday";
    d[7] = "Sunday";

    printf("Which year? ");
    scanf ("%d", &yyyy);

    yy = yyyy % 100;                                                                                                
    ypercent = yy + yy *(.25);


    result = yy * .1;                                                                                               
    result = result + (result/5.0);    

         for  (x = 0; x < ypercent; x++)                                                                                    
            {    
             if ((7 * x) > ypercent)                                                                                        
             break;                                                                                                 
             lastX = x;                                                                                             
            }

            ypercent = ypercent - lastX;


    printf("Janurary 1st, %d is on a %s :\n ", yyyy , d[ypercent]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the question is ....? Learn [ask].

Comment: `x++7` is a syntax error.  Did you mean `x += 7` ?

Comment: You also seem to be missing a closing `}` for your `for` loop.  I suggest posting code that you've at least compiled before asking for help.

Comment: You're also not allocating any memory for `d` before trying to assign through it.  And there are several missing semicolons.

Comment: AFAICS, the expression `result = result + (result/5.0):` will calculate 120% of the previous value of `result`, not 25% of it.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typos (such as missing semicolons and bracket)

You should declare d as an array of string pointers

```
char *d[7];
```

> I am just kind of stuck on how I would drop the decimal place?

All you need to do is cast it to an int. That would drop the decimal point.

```
int intresult = result + (result/5.0);
```

Note that because of the declaration you do not need to explicitly cast it

```
int intresult = (int)(result + (result/5.0));
```

however, you can truncate it but keep the value in floating point mode as

```
result = (int)(result + (result/5.0));
```

Comment: Note that `int(result + (result/5.0))` is valid in C++ but not in C; it would be written `(int)(result + (result/5.0))` in C.  If your C compiler accepts it, it is an extension over standard C syntax.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks typing too fast. Fixed